# Put layout into a listview at specific position after adapter is done

Tags: listview, layout, put

I've created a listview with adapter like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeG85.png)

now i need to put a layout after positions 3, 6, 9, etc. of the listview like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE3dP.png)

Can anyone tell me how i can do that and show me an example?

Comment: Is my first question in stackoverflow, apologize for my errors...

Comment: please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you,

Comment: I've accepted, thanks again for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is good enough just try to put your images inside the question and not on a link ;)

here a simple solution that I propose to you :

below each **item** (row) of your **Listview** put your view that needed to be add (define it in your xml file of your item) with a visibility as "GONE"

and in your adapter of the listView put it as VISIBILE when the position are 3,6,9... : **modulo** (remainder after division) by **3** is equal 0

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(position % 3 == 0) {
        yourViewExtension.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        yourViewExtension.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
```

if any trouble leave a comment

Good lluck

Comment: great ! , please put the answer as the right one, so the question would be resolved